# how to call method another activity inside tabhost from current adapter

Tags: android, methods, refresh, spinner, adapter

I have a tabhost with 3 activities A,B,C

activity A has a listview with current adapter, then inside adapter i do a sqlite insert, then in activity C also has a spinner listview with another adapter. In activity C, i added method to refresh spinner content and also method for onResume() with refresh spinner content inside it. If I did insert from adapter of listview from activity A, spinner did not get any changes (I hope it can get changes from onResume(), because there is some code to refresh spinner content), but nothing happened. Also if I call the method for refresh spinner content using below code :

```
Context mycontext;
((Activity C) mycontext).RefreshSpinner();
```

then also nothing happened. So how can I solve for this problem ? i did it with 2 ways. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will suggest you should use, FragmentTabHost instead of TabHost, and Fragments instead of activities for the contentview of each tab. And when a particular tab is clicked, you have your TabClickListnener on your activity to tell the fragment to refresh the views Using any Interface.

Comment: 1. Have a interface with reload() method. Implement the interface in the third Activity / Fragment.
2. When tab is click check for third tab and call the reload() method. 
3. Inside the reload method call your logic to reload data

Comment: but I have been using tabhost, so I need time to rebuild my application again, do you have another solution? thanks

Comment: there is one, But i dont recommend this as a Good Solution. 1. Implement tabclick listner in you root activity. 2. When third tab is clicked send a Local BroadCast Intent. 3. Register a Broadcast receiver in your third activity and listen for this intent. Once you receive the broadcast , reload your data. If you are not familiar with broadcast refer to tutorials

Answer (score 4):

Hie,
In your Adapter, if the context your application is getting is from Activity A suppose and you want to refresh Spinner content which is in Activity C, you can put your code in onResume() method of activity C, or adapter used to bind Spinner of Activity C. For this, you can either create a static method with a changes you want and update it first in the Adapter class of Activity A. Then that changes to reload a spinner with some random list/data which u have updated in Adapter for Activity A can be used directly in Adapter for Activity C or in onResume() method of Activity C. Else you create a list with updated data and bind that in Adapter for Activity A, and populate it in your onResume() method of Activity C passing context to it.

Comment: already put method refresh spinner in onResume of Activity C, but nothing happened

Comment: Can i get the code which you have put in your method to refresh or reload Spinner?.